# Create refinementList from string of values

Tags: algolia

I have data structured as follows:

```
{
  "id": 12345,
  "name": "Brother PJ-663 Direct A4 Thermal Mobile Printer",
  "type": "Thermal printer",
  "features": "USB, Mobile Print"
},
```

I'm trying to create a refinementList widget based on the values out of the features string (exploded), same as I do for type, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach or even possible.

How should I format the data to be able to create a single instantsearch.widgets.refinementList widget?

Also I use _tags instead and add each of those features as a tag, would it be possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to reformat (split by `,`) your data before indexing and index `features` and `type` as arrays:

```
{
  "id": 12345,
  "name": "Brother PJ-663 Direct A4 Thermal Mobile Printer",
  "type": [
    "Thermal printer"
  ],
  "features": [
    "USB", 
    "Mobile Print"
  ]
}
```

Then set those attributes as attributes for faceting in Algolia settings and you are good to go. The you can use [instantsearch.js](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/)'s [refinementList widget](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#refinementlist) to filter your results according those attributes.

I wouldn't go for `_tags` here as you have 2 different attributes you want to use for filtering and `_tags` won't allow you to do it in easy way.

Comment: I already tried that, but then I get as option to filter ["USB", "Mobile Print"], where I would like to end up with two options, "USB" and "Mobile Print".

Comment: Solved, the problem was the way I was uploading the data, thank you!